# Use Powershell to get *.lrc to match their *.flac names

Tags: powershell

For lyrics *.lrc files to work with android player, I have to have their titles match the *.flac song they are associated witn.  foobar2000 with the foo_uie_lyrics3 plugin retrieves lyrics, but names may not match and need renaming.  Example:

```
F:\Users\tfeth\MusicJen\Jen\Ripped Files\Alison Krauss\A Hundred Miles or More  A Collection> Get-ChildItem -Path . -Name
01 You’re Just a Country Boy.flac
02 Simple Love.flac
03 Jacob’s Dream.flac
04 Away Down the River.flac
05 Sawing on the Strings.flac
06 Down to the River to Pray.flac
07 Baby Mine.flac
08 Molly Bán (Bawn).flac
09 How’s the World Treating You.flac
10 The Scarlet Tide.flac
11 Whiskey Lullaby.flac
12 You Will Be My Ain True Love.flac
13 I Give You to His Heart.flac
14 Get Me Through December.flac
15 Missing You.flac
16 Lay Down Beside Me.flac
Alison Krauss - Away Down the River.lrc
Alison Krauss - Baby Mine.txt
Alison Krauss - Down to the River to Pray.lrc
Alison Krauss - Get Me Through December.lrc
Alison Krauss - I Give You to His Heart.lrc
Alison Krauss - Lay Down Beside Me.lrc
Alison Krauss - Missing You.txt
Alison Krauss - Sawing on the Strings.lrc
Alison Krauss - Simple Love.lrc
Alison Krauss - The Scarlet Tide.lrc
Alison Krauss - You Will Be My Ain True Love.lrc
Brad Paisley - Whiskey Lullaby.lrc
```

---

So I have to drop the " -" portion and append " " portion from the matching song, (or just replace the whole filename with matching .flac filename).

I imagine the script to solve this would sort the filenames into two sets, {*.flac} and {*.lrc, *.txt}, iterate over the later, finding the filename in the first set that contains the longest matching substring for each, then renaming the file with the found files filename.

As there might be mismatches, prompt with the matches and offer All or Confirm-match-by match. Mock-up:

```
01 You’re Just a Country Boy.flac
==no match
02 Simple Love.flac
   Alison Krauss - Simple Love.lrc
03 Jacob’s Dream.flac
==no match
04 Away Down the River.flac
   Alison Krauss - Away Down the River.lrc
05 Sawing on the Strings.flac
   Alison Krauss - Sawing on the Strings.lrc
06 Down to the River to Pray.flac
   Alison Krauss - Down to the River to Pray.lrc
07 Baby Mine.flac
   Alison Krauss - Baby Mine.txt
08 Molly Bán (Bawn).flac
==no match
09 How’s the World Treating You.flac
==no match
10 The Scarlet Tide.flac
   Alison Krauss - The Scarlet Tide.lrc
11 Whiskey Lullaby.flac
   Brad Paisley - Whiskey Lullaby.lrc
12 You Will Be My Ain True Love.flac
   Alison Krauss - You Will Be My Ain True Love.lrc
13 I Give You to His Heart.flac
   Alison Krauss - I Give You to His Heart.lrc
14 Get Me Through December.flac
   Alison Krauss - Get Me Through December.lrc
15 Missing You.flac
   Alison Krauss - Missing You.txt
16 Lay Down Beside Me.flac
   Alison Krauss - Lay Down Beside Me.lrc
-------------------------------------------------------------
Rename-all, Confirm-each-pair (a,c):
```

Comment: Sounds like you know what to do! What's the question?

Comment: Please show an example output of what you want to have happen. It would be helpful if you attempt to code the solution yourself. Seeing the code helps explain a lot about what you are trying to do and gives SO users the opportunity to help you where you are stuck.

Comment: The question is for help to automate this as there will be thousand of files ultimately.

Comment: Well, OK. then put together a user list is a file, read it in, and loop for results.